# TypeScript type narrowing with discriminated union and callback not working as expected

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to do a type narrowing on a `User` with an argument and then pass that user (which should be narrowed to either a `Customer` or `Business`) to a handler function later. However, TypeScript doesn't recognize the discriminated union and returns just a `User` in the callback.

```js
interface Customer {
  role: 'customer';
}

interface Business {
  role: 'business';
}

type User = Customer | Business;

function findUserByRole<TUser extends User>(role: TUser['role'], handler: (user: TUser) => any) {
  // something
}

findUserByRole('customer', customer => {
  customer // User
  customer.role // 'customer' | 'business'
})
```

I know that I could technically fix this by just defining `(customer: Customer) => ...` in the handler function but the code shown above is simplified and doing that in the actual application code would be very annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following solution will have `user` in `handler` inferred automatically:

```
function findUserByRole<T extends User["role"]>(
    role: T, handler: (user: Extract<User, { role: T }>) => any) {
    // something
}
```

```
findUserByRole('customer', customer => {
    customer // Customer
    customer.role // "customer"
})

findUserByRole('business', business => {
    business // Business
    business.role // "business"
})
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=3&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbaZAbwFgAoZS5KHAGwgC5kByBLXAqZgbnIF9y5UJFiIUAISygImTMXJVqdRiwBGUkDMw9%20gsmACeABxQBVTIQC8advkIAfZJMzTZvMuRjoQCMMBwgyDCgACbm0OIGAErKADwAKsgQAB6QICFy4VAA2gBENPS5ALoAfAAUClQFKvEANMgAFnDp9FBMZVjQTACiqVCIYLFZ9URK9EyJfCUAlMiWJcjNBrOkFFQA9OvImHZgDaAA5roeZMHpWZEx9GWstpzM9WzYdlBzC6uKTxyEmzbPnJVKF8XgA6arIX65YGcXL8aZ6M5hCxQS7KG7qFyaWQPZAY1xyebyNaUPFYuS-Zz4wG4jRaMHKCFbXKkrSwsh8aZAA)

Comment: Thanks! How does `Extract` work though--does it mean something special to TS? Because when I replaced it with its literal equivalent (`User extends { role: T} ? User : never`) TypeScript just converted `customer` into a `never` type.

Comment: There is nothing really fancy about `Extract` type itself. But when we type it as `Extract<User, { role: T }`, we can make use of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in TS, which must be of the form `MyType<T> = T extends ... ` The `T` on its own before `extends` clause is the important thing. With distributive conditional types each union constituent can be processed on its own ("distributed over the conditional type"), so we can filter the right user by the given role in the function argument.